# phpexcel remove multiple rows in sequence with comments on cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

My problem is that I try to delete multiple rows in a loop. I want to delete only 'good' rows and leave bad ones with marks.
It looks like this:

```
$this->writeCellErrorData($objPHPExcel);//write coments a to cell and set bg to red
//get unique rows array
foreach($this->celConstraintViolation as $columnNum=>$row){
            foreach($row as $rowNum=>$data){
                if(!in_array($rowNum, $this->errorRowsArr)){
                    $this->errorRowsArr[]=$rowNum;
                }
            }
        }
        sort($this->errorRowsArr);
        $this->errorRowsArr= array_reverse($this->errorRowsArr);
        for($i=$this->celArrRowNum; $i>1; $i--){                   //reverse loop
            if(!in_array($i, $this->errorRowsArr)){
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($i,1);   //remove rows
            }
        }
```

after that I save the file. While the bg color is where it should be, it seems that comments are where they were before the removal. Is there a way to remove rows so that comments move where they should?
To add comments I use this line:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->
getComment(array_search($columnNum, $this->header).$rowNum)->getText()->
createTextRun($this->cellErrorMessages[$data[0]]);
```

Comment: At first, i would suggest to not work with Excel grid, as working area, use Excel only for display - seperate calculations from representation, such an order will make debugging easier. If you want to mess with data, read required area inside array and afterwards, work around it, with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, Its worked me:

```
$filename = 'path/example.xls';
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();


    $row_id  = 1; // deleted row id
    $number_rows = 2; // number of rows count 
if ($objWorksheet != NULL) {
            if ($objWorksheet->removeRow($row_id, $number_rows)) {
                $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
                $objWriter->save($filename;
            }
        }
```